Origin of the quote "I suggest you rethink your strategy"
I remember a movie about a military academy. One scene has two cadets fighting in the barracks. The commander of cadets breaks up the fight and tells the two cadets, "I suggest you rethink your strategy." The quote always stayed with me, it was an unusual response, as opposed to "Knock it off" or "Get ahold of yourselves". I have racked my brain trying to figure out what movie I saw it in, it wasn't Taps but it was a very similar movie. The movie was in English, filmed in the U.S. with well-known actors, and would have been released prior to 2000, probably in the 1980s.

Thought this might be Toy Soldiers (1991), but I just grabbed the subtitle file and a text search didn't find the phrase.

The quote is "I think maybe you better go back to your quarters and rethink your strategy", and it is from the TV series Tour of Duty Season 2 Episode 6 Sleeping Dogs. This is the scene:




Thank you very much, grej. This one phrase has been rolling around in my head for years. I just assumed it was a military academy, it didn't occur to me to look within military movies or TV shows. Gotta love Stack Exchange.
